# Accessing Array from Handlebars

Tags: arrays, handlebars.js

```
const data = {
 customer:{
  name:[{
         user 1
        },
        {
         user 2
        },
        {
         user 3
        }],
  users : 2
 }
}
```

Printing data of newest user in a view template using:

```
{{#each data}}
  {{this.customer.name.[this.customer.users]}}
{{/each}}
```

The output is

:
N/A

Are There any solution to print the newest user data ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

But first, you will need to determine which property of each `name` object you wish to render. You have included invalid JavaScript for each object in your `name` array (ex., `{ user 1 }`), and so, I must guess on how you plan to use these objects. I am going to assume these objects have a shape like `{ value: "user 1" }`.

Since you wish to lookup an object on the `customer.name` array using another variable, `customer.user` as the index, you will need to use the built-in [Lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) helper. In fact, you will need to use it *twice*: once to get the object out of `customer.name` at the `customer.user` index, and then to get the value of the `value` property off of the returned object.

Fortunately, Handlebars support [Subexpressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions) to do this kind of lookup nesting. Our template now becomes:

```
<p>
  Newest username is...
  {{lookup (lookup customer.name customer.users) 'value'}}
</p>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cxu59opz/) for reference.